# Reassign multiple records to record array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply a transformation to certain columns of a record array and reassign these values. What is the canonical way to do this?

```
List = [['a',.3,.3],
        ['b',-.5,.4]]

Arr = np.rec.fromrecords(List,names=['id','var1','var2'])
```

And I want to apply some scaling to some variables. I'll let this be an example but in general the scaling may be more complex than subtracting means.

```
scale = lambda x: x - x.mean(0)
```

This does not work

```
Arr[['var1','var2']].mean(0)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So I have to convert to an unstructured array first, but then how to reassign back to the record array? Do I loop?

```
Unstr = Arr[['var1','var2']].view('float').reshape(len(Arr),-1)

Arr[['var1','var2']] = scale(Unstr)

IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

Comment: Nice nickname for a pythonista :-)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the jab was directed at Python... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you scale variables one by one?

```
In [13]: %paste
import numpy as np

List = [['a',.3,.3],
        ['b',-.5,.4]]

scale = lambda x: x - x.mean()
Arr = np.rec.fromrecords(List,names=['id','var1','var2'])

vars_to_scale = ['var1', 'var2']
for var in vars_to_scale:
    Arr[var] = scale(Arr[var])
print Arr
## -- End pasted text --
[('a', 0.4, -0.04999999999999999) ('b', -0.4, 0.050000000000000044)]
```

Comment: Right, so that's how it has to be done... with a loop? That was the obvious way but I thought `numpy` would be high-level enough to allow me to avoid such constructs (otherwise it doesn't offer much value above `fortran`/`C`?).

Comment: Well, working with `numpy.ndarray` provides enough high-levelness to beat both `Fortran` and `C`. But, AFAIK, `numpy.recarray` is a structure made of _several_ arrays. You can view several arrays as one, but you can't work with several arrays at once, especially you can't assign a sequence of arrays with one array. Also the Zen of Python teaches that explicit is better than implicit, and what could be explicit than a loop? :)

Comment: Coming from R I hate loops but knowing that a recarray is comprises several ndarrays helps me accept that looping is unavoidable in this case.